# Максимальный зум - не видно линий

Tags: yandex-maps-api

При использовании "new ymaps.Polyline" рисуются линии но при макс. зуме пропадают некоторые из них. Как исправить?
https://smart-destiny.ru/karta/test.php
Чтобы увидеть надо кликнуть на карте и зуммить.

Comment: Вам следует задать этот вопрос в техподдержку Яндекс, может что-то сломано. Однако, мне не удалось воспроизвести на вашем примере.

Answer (score 0):

Это проблема SVG-графики. Возможно это баг в её реализации на API Карт.
На версии 2.1.77, которая из девелоперской вот-вот перейдёт в релиз вижу уже canvas, там всё рисуется верно.

Подключать сейчас нужно либо прямым указанием версии, либо через **-dev**:

```
https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1.77?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU
https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1-dev?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU
```

Вот в текущей 2.1.76: https://jsfiddle.net/Coroner1st/7tma3jdk/27/

А вот на свежей  2.1.77: https://jsfiddle.net/Coroner1st/7tma3jdk/26/